# How a validate a phone number (number entered is present)

Tags: java, gwt, phone-number

I have created a Gwt application which has a form for user registration which contains a phone number textbox. I have applied a regex to validate its a ten digit number. Now is there any way to check that the number entered by user is not fake like if he is not entering number like 1234567890 or 0000000000.

One technique I know is to send verification code on this number, but apart from that is there any other way.

Also if send msg is the only option is there any gwt client side to send immediate msg to that number.